# Lion adding an empty desktop when full-screening an application

Tags: macos, spaces

I've noticed the following:

1. I have 1 desktop and a couple of applications open
   [image]
2. I drag an application to a new desktop (2 in this case)
   [image]
3. I 'full screen' both applications
4. A blank desktop is automatically added before both fullscreen apps.
   [image]

Anybody know a way to stop it from doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Full-screening an application puts that application on a new "desktop" to the right of the desktop it was on.  You started with Safari on desktop 2 and Sparrow on desktop 3 and fullscreened both, which left desktop 2 and 3 blank (they don't get closed just because they are blank) and the fullscreened apps to the right of where they were.

If you don't want the blanks, just fullscreen from your original desktop directly.

This is working the way it should as far as I can see.

Comment: Yes, this is normal.  There is no benefit to moving an app into a new space before full screening it.  Fullscreening an app creates a space for itself as part of the proces, as David says.  However, when you un-fullscreen an app, it will return to the space that it came from originally, so if for example you have 2 desktops, one with mail and twitter and such like in it, and the 2nd with safari and iCal for example, then full screening Safari will create a new space, leaving iCal in a space on it;s own.  When you un fullscreen Safari, it will always go back to the space that it came from

Answer (score 2):

Take out step 2. Applications automatically make their own space when they go fullscreen in Lion.